# I don't know R and I want to calculate Spearman correlation in R with a given alpha and want to know the p value

Tags: r, correlation

I don't know R and I want to calculate Spearman correlation in R with a given alpha and want to know the p value. I have data in CSV format. How do I do it?

Please give step by step solution. I don't have any packages and no libraries.
Just finished installing R.

Comment: Initial step is to read the data in `R` i..e. `df1 <- read.csg('yourfile.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: Hello Rishabh. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your post. You'll get higher quality help, faster, if you provide a small amount of data, the code you've already tried, and an explanation of the output you're working to produce.

Comment: Hi Rishabh.  Your question is getting downvoted a lot because it looks like you're just asking for people to solve your problem for you.  Good/upvoted StackOverflow questions don't just say "help me", they give some indication that you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself and then explained in detail where you got stuck ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spearman correlations can be produced with the `corr.test()` function from the `psych` package.

To illustrate use of Spearman correlation with ranked data, we'll create two ranked variables for the Motor Trend Cars data set, `mtcars`, install the `psych` package, and then run `corr.test()`.

```
install.packages("psych")
library(psych)

# create a couple of rank variables with mtcars data set

# sort & create rank for wt
mtcars <- mtcars[order(mtcars$wt),]
mtcars$rank_wt <- 1:nrow(mtcars)
# sort & create rank for qsec
mtcars <- mtcars[order(mtcars$qsec),]
mtcars$rank_qsec <- 1:nrow(mtcars)

result <- corr.test(mtcars$rank_wt,mtcars$rank_qsec,method = "spearman",
          alpha = 0.05)

print(result, short = FALSE)
```

Output from the test looks like this:

```
> print(result, short = FALSE)
Call:corr.test(x = mtcars$rank_wt, y = mtcars$rank_qsec, method = "spearman", 
    alpha = 0.05)
Correlation matrix 
[1] -0.22
Sample Size 
[1] 32
Probability values  adjusted for multiple tests. 
[1] 0.23

 Confidence intervals based upon normal theory.  To get bootstrapped values, try cor.ci
      raw.lower raw.r raw.upper raw.p lower.adj upper.adj
NA-NA     -0.53 -0.22      0.14  0.23     -0.53      0.14
```

Next, we'll run a Pearson correlation on the original data to compare results.

```
# compare with pearson R for continuous variables
result <- corr.test(mtcars$wt,mtcars$qsec,alpha = 0.05)
print(result, short = FALSE)
```

...and the output:

```
> print(result, short = FALSE)
Call:corr.test(x = mtcars$wt, y = mtcars$qsec, alpha = 0.05)
Correlation matrix 
[1] -0.17
Sample Size 
[1] 32
Probability values  adjusted for multiple tests. 
[1] 0.34

 Confidence intervals based upon normal theory.  To get bootstrapped values, try cor.ci
      raw.lower raw.r raw.upper raw.p lower.adj upper.adj
NA-NA     -0.49 -0.17      0.19  0.34     -0.49      0.19
```

The two techniques produce similar results. In the original data, `wt` has a slight negative correlation with `qsec`, but it is not signficantly different from zero at alpha = 0.05. The magnitude of the Spearman correlation is slightly larger than the Pearson correlation, but it's still not significantly different from zero at alpha = 0.05.

### Comparison to JASP

In the comments the OP asked why the statistics software JASP produces different results than R. When I installed JASP, loaded the `mtcars` data with the rank columns I created, and ran Spearman's rho, JASP produced the same results as R within rounding error.

[image]

Comment: I am getting different results for with JASP and R. Why?

Comment: Hello @RishabhShrivastava . I downloaded JASP, loaded the `mtcars` data frame with the rank variables I created, and calculated Spearman's rho. I obtained the same answer in JASP as I did in R, within rounding error. See my updated answer for details.

Comment: Is it really necessary to create ranked columns? Wouldn't  ranking break the relationship between column A and Column B?

Comment: Spearman's ρ is also known as [Spearman's rank correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman's_rank_correlation_coefficient). It is a non-parametric measure of rank correlation, i.e. the statistical dependence between two ranked variables. I created two ranked variables specifically to have the right kind of data to use with Spearman's ρ. If you're not interested in comparing ranked values and your original variables are at the interval / ratio level of measurement, you should use the Pearson correlation.

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot. I got it right without arranging in ranks. I guess the function/software does that itself.

Comment: You made my day @LenGriski Thanks a lot. May Gods save you from these deadly times of pandemic and lock down May you live a wonderful life.

Comment: @RishabhShrivastava - You're welcome. If the answer helped you, please accept it.

Comment: How do I do that?